# how to add a word where the cursor is in javascript

Tags: javascript, text-cursor

I want to add a word, where the cursor is. It should be something like this:

```
addWordToTextarea(word){
 var tmpMyTextArea = document.getElementById('myTextArea').innerHTML.value;
 var tmpCursorPositionInTextarea = document.getCursorFromId('myTextArea'); //does something like this function exist?
 if(tmpCursorPositionInTextarea){
  //add word to tmpMyTextarea on position where cursor is;
 } else {
  tmpMyTextArea = word;
 } 
}
```

Comment: have a look at `selectionStart` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextAreaElement

Comment: thank you that was the answer i got it with selectionstart
```
document.getElementById('prismEditorId').addEventListener('click', e =>{
        this.pos = e.target.selectionStart;
        console.log("pos"+ this.pos);
 })
```

Comment: @qianfranco Add an answer then.